# Understanding flow curves of an hydraulic directional proportional valve

Tags: hydraulics, valves

In the picture below you can see the command signal to flow curves for a proportional valve I'm using. Since I'm using it to control the speed of a cylinder I was looking at the looped flow path diagram (I think it should be the right scenario). The first thing I'm not sure is if 10 bar is the pressure drop per metering edge ($\Delta P _{PA }=\Delta P _{BT }= 10 bar$). Moreover, I'would have expected between the curve at 10 bar and 50 bar a coefficient of $\sqrt 5=2.23$, while in the graph is lower.
I'd appreciate if someone could give me an explanation.

[image]

Comment: I would expect the curves to show the flow per percentage of command signal for the indicated pressure drops across PA or PB in the left figure and across PT in the right figure.